# Customise SystemTray Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone, system-tray

How to customise `SystemTray` like **Bing Weather** App ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution:

```
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="true"
shell:SystemTray.BackgroundColor="Transparent"
shell:SystemTray.Opacity="0.0"
```

Comment: I try to place this Code at App.xaml , But it Crash My App , How can I do that

Comment: Try to put it in your page, MainPage.xaml for example